# Convert Enum to Binary (via Integer or something similar)

Tags: enums, binary, ada

I have an Ada enum with 2 values `type Polarity is (Normal, Reversed)`, and I would like to convert them to 0, 1 (or True, False--as Boolean seems to implicitly play nice as binary) respectively, so I can store their values as specific bits in a byte. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: +1 for a familiar _Star Trek_ shibboleth, but it may may help to elaborate on your goal, e.g. external system interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all I needed to do was `pragma Pack([type name]);` (in which 'type name' is the type composed of Polarity) to compress the value down to a single bit.

Answer (score 3):

[*3.5.5 Operations of Discrete Types*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-5-5.html) include the `function S'Pos(Arg : S'Base)`, which "returns the position number of the value of `Arg`, as a value of type *universal integer*." Hence,

```
Polarity'Pos(Normal) = 0
Polarity'Pos(Reversed) = 1
```

You can change the numbering using [*13.4 Enumeration Representation Clauses*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-13-4.html).

...and, of course:

```
Boolean'Val(Polarity'Pos(Normal)) = False
Boolean'Val(Polarity'Pos(Reversed)) = True
```

Comment: The `type Boolean is (False, True)` in [package Standard](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-1.html) has the same numbering.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is a lookup table:

```
Bool_Polarity : constant Array(Polarity) of Boolean 
              := (Normal=>False, Reversed => True);
```

then use it as

```
 B Boolean := Bool_Polarity(P);
```

Of course there is nothing wrong with using the 'Pos attribute, but the LUT makes the mapping readable and very obvious.

As it is constant, you'd like to hope it optimises away during the constant folding stage, and it seems to: I have used similar tricks compiling for AVR with very acceptable executable sizes (down to 0.6k to independently drive 2 stepper motors)

Comment: How does this address the `specific bits in a byte` part of the Question ?

Comment: NWS: you are quite correct that it addresses the value conversion part of the question, but not packing bits in a byte. For that, the Byte_As_Record_T part of your answer will do nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a record type with a representation clause:

```
procedure Main is

   type Byte_T is mod 2**8-1;
   for Byte_T'Size use 8;

   type Filler7_T is mod 2**7-1;
   for Filler7_T'Size use 7;

   type Polarity_T is (Normal,Reversed);
   for Polarity_T use (Normal => 0, Reversed => 1);
   for Polarity_T'Size use 1;

   type Byte_As_Record_T is record
      Filler   : Filler7_T;
      Polarity : Polarity_T;
   end record;

   for Byte_As_Record_T use record
      Filler at 0 range 0 .. 6;
      Polarity at 0 range 7 .. 7;
   end record;
   for Byte_As_Record_T'Size use 8;

   function Convert is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion
     (Source => Byte_As_Record_T,
      Target => Byte_T);

   function Convert is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion
     (Source => Byte_T,
      Target => Byte_As_Record_T);

begin

   -- TBC
   null;

end Main;
```

As `Byte_As_Record_T` & `Byte_T` are the same size, you can use `unchecked conversion` to convert between the types safely.

The representation clause for `Byte_As_Record_T` allows you to specify which bits/bytes to place your `polarity_t` in. (i chose the 8th bit)

My definition of `Byte_T` might not be what you want, but as long as it is 8 bits long the principle should still be workable. From Byte_T you can also safely upcast to `Integer` or `Natural` or `Positive`. You can also use the same technique to go directly to/from a 32 bit Integer to/from a 32 bit record type.

Answer (score 1):

Two points here:

1) Enumerations **are already stored as binary**. Everything is. In particular, your enumeration, as defined above, will be stored as a `0` for `Normal` and a `1` for `Reversed`, unless you go out of your way to tell the compiler to use other values.

If you want to get that value out of the enumeration as an `Integer` rather than an enumeration value, you have two options. The `'pos()` attribute will return a 0-based number for that enumeration's position in the enumeration, and `Unchecked_Conversion` will return the actual value the computer stores for it. (There is no difference in the value, unless an enumeration representation clause was used).

2) Enumerations are nice, but **don't reinvent `Boolean`**. If your enumeration can only ever have two values, you don't gain anything useful by making a custom enumeration, and you lose a lot of useful properties that `Boolean` has. Booleans can be directly selected off of in loops and `if` checks. Booleans have `and`, `or`, `xor`, etc. defined for them. Booleans can be put into packed arrays, and then those same operators are defined bitwise across the whole array.

A particular pet peeve of mine is when people end up defining themselves a custom boolean with the logic reversed (so its true condition is 0). If you do this, the ghost of [Ada Lovelace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace) will come back from the grave and force you to listen to an exhaustive explanation of how to calculate Bernoulli sequences with a Difference Engine. Don't let this happen to you!

So if it would never make sense to have a third enumeration value, **you just name objects something appropriate describing the `True` condition** (eg: `Reversed_Polarity : Boolean;`), and go on your merry way.

Comment: I have many different 2-value types in my application (each with a different semantic meaning), and many functions that take various combinations of those types. I don't want to be able to accidentally put one in place of another because both are Boolean. Moreover, many of these don't semantically mean anything similar to True and False. Furthermore, Boolean has only one feature useful to my application that may or may not be missing from an enum solution, and that is the one I'm asking about in my question.

Comment: Otherwise, I'll look through the options you listed in your first section and see if they work in my application. Thanks. :)

Comment: OK. Don't blame me when you get that visit from the Ghost of Programmers Past though. I warned you. :-)